# How can I switch the function and control keys on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboard-layout

I have an **ASUS X51R laptop** and the left function/control keys are swapped as shown in the picture below?

Is there some way to remap these keys so that CTRL is on the far left as on a standard keyboard layout?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's sadly no way to do this in the OS, since the Fn key isn't actually recognized by Windows.

You might actually be able to do it in your BIOS setup screen, but it's unlikely.

Comment: if it really isn't possible, can someone then lessen the pain by explaining why someone thought it would be a good idea to have the function key, used 0.01% of the time in an easier position to reach than the CTRL key, used 99.99% of the time? Is there a reason for this? Trying to press CTRL-SHIFT-ALT with one hand is painful and I'm constantly hitting Function-S to save, etc. since it is a kinesthetic habit I've had for 25 years now.

Comment: has ctrl+s for save been around that long now? time flies.

Comment: I guess wordstar SAVE was Ctrl-K-S, but Microsoft Word for DOS 5.5 was definitely CTRL-S, so, 24 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the function key on my laptop (Latitude D830) . It doesn't produce a scan code by itself.
I verified using Keytweak http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/ 
Which is an excellent tool for remapping keys in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Found this (assuming a Windows OS). I've not read it all but I think it can help.

http://www.autohotkey.net/~daonlyfreez/tutorials/3p/Veil/fnkey.htm

Uses Autohotkey. It might only be able to remap the <kbd>F1</kbd> function keys rather than the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. Any good?