# Remap [Function] key on a Gateway laptop

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Since the motherboard on my HP laptop died, I'm temporarily using my wife's Gateway laptop.  It's a nice little computer, except the [Function] key is at the bottom left of the keyboard, where the CTRL key should be, and the CTRL key is next to it.  I know that the [Function] key is not interpreted by the OS, only at the hardware level, so is there any way to switch these keys?  Having the [Function] key there is SO unnatural.

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate RTM

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I switch the function and control keys on my laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/35228/how-can-i-switch-the-function-and-control-keys-on-my-laptop)

Answer (score 2):

As the FN key is not handled by the Windows keyboard driver, any remapping of the it is impossible by any Windows utility that switches keys, because it doesn't generate any scan-codes.

You should therefore regard your BIOS to see if a "Swap FN and CTRL" option already exists. If not, maybe a future BIOS upgrade will solve the problem.

In the meantime, you can use this solution (just joking):

[image]

Comment: hahaha... nice solution.  hack yer hardware ftw!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm) are some suggestions/applications for you to check out.

It lists third party software, registry tweaks and other things to help you remap your keyboard.

[image]