# How to reprogram the social media key on a gateway laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remap [Function] key on a Gateway laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/52818/remap-function-key-on-a-gateway-laptop)

My parents recently got a [Gateway NV Series](http://www.gateway.com/programs/nvseries/index.php) with a social media key.  Can I reprogram it to something else?

Comment: What is a social media key?

Comment: One of those silly custom keys they put on some keyboards and laptops... like mine has ones for media, search, webcam, etc. I never use them. OP, you're looking for something called a keyboard remapper. This is one random one I found via google that claims it can handle 'special' keys that aren't on standard keyboards. http://www.thetechhub.com/2009/07/remap-keyboard-keys-on-windows.html